# Voting for moving a question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, migration

Couldn't there be some simply mechanism for moving a question to a different...  sub-site?<sup>1</sup>  Either I'm missing some information or it's plain missing. We're given two options, close and flag.

- Flagging is for serious cases, and if the question isn't totally misplaced (I just feel it would live better elsewhere), so there's no point.
- Closing is for bad question or question not unfit for the current sub-site. Voting to close is plain negative. Not an option in case of a moderately good question.
- Leaving a comment "this question would be better fit for..." leads to copypasting the question, even worse.

Don't get me wrong, I don't think it should be *easy* to move a question or let moving questions became the favorite way of getting rid of bad questions. But there should be a way to vote for it.

My proposal is pretty simple:

Allow voting for different actions and let the votes compete. There could be some weighting, which should be trivial to get about right (the current state means zero weight for "move" votes, so let's start low).

---

<sup>1</sup> It's impossible for me to call it a "site", but you understand.

Comment: flagging is quite appropriate if the close migrations aren't available.

Comment: With the new tag the sidebar now included a question s about adding a certain specific site to the migration list. It's worth look at it and thinking about the topics raised therein. Migration is a tricky business and it requires some knowledge of the target site to do well.

Comment: @dmckee No, I'm not asking about any migrations list, and not  complaining about only 5 of them available **somewhere**. I'm proposing the *possibility to vote for migration rather than closing*. I'd never vote for closing if the question is plausible on a given sub-site, but I'd gladly vote to move it to a better place.

Comment: Ah ... I guess I see. On physics--where I'm a diamond mod--we have a unofficial policy of never migrating on-topic questions without the OP's request, and we expect the OP to deliver that request as a flag. So, I retract my statements above (excepting that migration is a tricky thing) and instead offer my opposition to the idea.

Comment: @dmckee That's better. But you expect the OP to do *anything*? Really? :D But most OPs asking OTs are pretty clueless, which means someone has to write a comment... I'm not really opposed the idea of not migrating it without OP's request, but IMHO there should be some automation. Let's say, someone votes for moving, the OP gets a message, agrees, someone else votes for it, and it happens. It may be wrong (but only rarely) and it may be worth closing anyway, but I'm not precluding this. It's all a matter of weights. Better then commenting and surely better than reposting!

Comment: *"But you expect the OP to do anything?"* No, they mostly sit tight. But as long as the question is acceptable where it is then I see that as the OP's choice.

Comment: Can the OPs be allowed to move the questions themselves once flagged (or suggested)?

Comment: @TJ- This would be best IMHO. The OP is allowed to place a question on any site, so why shouldn't they be allowed to move it? Moving a question without user's request should be also possible, but rare (some users just ask once and never come again).

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, moving questions between different Stack Exchange communities is a pretty rough experience for the user; we generally try to minimize it.

Flagging is the appropriate way to indicate that you think a question belongs on another site. In some cases, a question *could* fit on multiple sites...if it isn't explicitly off-topic on the site where it was originally asked, there's no reason to move it. If the question goes unanswered for a while and you think the OP might have better luck on another site, you can always leave a comment to that effect. But we really don't want to encourage a lot of migrating.